# I am installin sharp in mac m1, for Gatsby js but it is showing error /usr/local/include/vips/vips8:35:10: fatal error: 'glib-object.h' file not found

Tags: node.js

I run this command npm

```
install --arch=arm64 --platform=linuxmusl sharp
```

It showed this error

```
npm ERR! warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/common.cc:24:
npm ERR! /usr/local/include/vips/vips8:35:10: fatal error: 'glib-object.h' file not found
npm ERR! #include <glib-object.h>
npm ERR!          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp-darwin-x64/src/common.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `$ brew install vips` allowed me to install Gatsby. I'm not sure if it would fix the issue with installing sharp directly, but it looks like it would be worth a try, based on your error message.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/30528#discussioncomment-544675